# LOAD DATA INFILE consistently skips first line, while not set to IGNORE

Tags: csv, mariadb, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load a csv file with stock prices into a prices table.
The csv file has 3 lines that I want to ignore, including a blank one.
When I set `IGNORE 1 LINES`, it runs into an error processing the column headers.
When I set `IGNORE 2 LINES`, it consistently skips the first line of data.
All other data is loaded just fine, starting from the 2nd data row ("11-03-2020" in this case).

How do I fix this, without changing the data in the csv?

The **csv** looks like this:

```
"Some instructions"

"date";"price"
"12-03-2020";133.08
"11-03-2020";143.68
"10-03-2020";149.14
...
```

The **CREATE TABLE** code:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `isin` CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    `price_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `isin_date` (`isin`, `price_date`),
    CONSTRAINT `prices_stocks` FOREIGN KEY (`isin`) REFERENCES `stocks` (`isin`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
AUTO_INCREMENT=157532
;
```

The **LOAD DATA SQL** statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'price_history_LU0792910050.csv'
        REPLACE INTO TABLE stock_db.prices
            CHARACTER SET utf8
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
            ESCAPED BY '"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            IGNORE 2 LINES
            (@vdate, @vprice)
        SET
            isin = 'LU0792910050',
            price_date = STR_TO_DATE(@vdate, '%d-%m-%Y'),
            price = @vprice;
```

hexdump of an example csv:

```
00000000: EF BB BF 22 44 65 20 69  6E 73 74 65 6C 6C 69 6E  ..."De instellin
00000010: 67 65 6E 20 76 61 6E 20  75 77 20 45 78 63 65 6C  gen van uw Excel
00000020: 2D 73 6F 66 74 77 61 72  65 20 6B 75 6E 6E 65 6E  -software kunnen
00000030: 20 64 65 20 77 65 65 72  67 61 76 65 20 76 61 6E   de weergave van
00000040: 20 6F 6E 64 65 72 73 74  61 61 6E 64 65 20 67 65   onderstaande ge
00000050: 67 65 76 65 6E 73 20 62  65 C3 AF 6E 76 6C 6F 65  gevens be..nvloe
00000060: 64 65 6E 20 64 6F 6F 72  20 64 65 20 63 65 6C 6F  den door de celo
00000070: 70 6D 61 61 6B 20 76 61  6E 20 64 65 20 67 65 67  pmaak van de geg
00000080: 65 76 65 6E 73 63 61 74  65 67 6F 72 69 65 20 28  evenscategorie (
00000090: 62 69 6A 76 2E 20 61 61  6E 74 61 6C 20 69 6E 20  bijv. aantal in 
000000A0: 70 6C 61 61 74 73 20 76  61 6E 20 64 61 74 75 6D  plaats van datum
000000B0: 29 2E 22 0D 0A 0D 0A 22  64 61 74 65 22 3B 22 70  )."...."date";"p
000000C0: 72 69 63 65 22 0D 0A 22  31 35 2D 30 37 2D 32 30  rice".."15-07-20
000000D0: 32 30 22 3B 35 31 2E 37  36 0D 0A 22 31 34 2D 30  20";51.76.."14-0
000000E0: 37 2D 32 30 32 30 22 3B  35 31 2E 31 37 0D 0A 22  7-2020";51.17.."
000000F0: 31 33 2D 30 37 2D 32 30  32 30 22 3B 35 31 2E 30  13-07-2020";51.0
00000100: 33 0D 0A 22 31 30 2D 30  37 2D 32 30 32 30 22 3B  3.."10-07-2020";
```

(Hexdump was not installed on Synology, so used Python [hexdump](https://pypi.org/project/hexdump/). Hope this works)

Comment: Make sure the file really has CRLF, not just LF.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames
The file has CRLF and not just LF. Any other ideas or thoughts? It's really peculiar.

Comment: Get a hex dump of the first few lines; there may be something we are missing.

Comment: @RickJames, how do I get a hex dump? Would be grateful if you can add some instructions.

Comment: Unix or Windows?

Comment: @RickJames: Windows or Linux based Synology

Comment: Look for `od -c` or `hexdump`

Comment: @RickJames: I've edited the post to include an example hexdump. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"12-03-2020"` cannot be put directly be put into a `DATE` column.  Instead, put it into an @ variable, then use `str_to_date(...)`.  (Let us know if you need help; there are many examples floating around.)

I see `C3 AF`, which is utf8 for `ï`, as in `... beïnvloegen ...` -- Does that sound "right"?  `CHARACTER SET utf8` should have *read* it correctly.

The initial `EF BB BF` is "BOM".  I don't know if `LOAD FILE` is smart enough to silently skip over it.  This may be causing your problem.  One approach is to edit the file to remove the first 3 bytes.

Later comes `0D 0A 0D 0A`, which matches your description of there being 3 header lines, the second being blank.  And `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` should be correct for that.

Comment: "12-03-2020" -> I believe I did put it in a variable before converting to a date in my SQL statement above.
" ï " is indeed the character used there ... beïnvloeden ... is correct and means to influence

I guess it's the "BOM" that throws the LOAD FILE off. I've adjusted the script to delete all lines before the header to work around the issue, but I was really curious why this was happening (and hoping to skip the edit before loading).

RESPECT by the way... I'm obviously not a pro, but it looks like you read hex like a character in The Matrix.

Comment: @Joost - Hehe.  I answer so many charset questions that I developed a web page that lets me paste almost anything into it; it will automatically convert to/from hex, and deduce some of the likely scenarios of screwups.  I'm especially proud of this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  I discovered BOM a long time ago:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark